# How to extract the attribute's value in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a html file say:

```
<html>...  
  <li id="123"></li>
  <li id="3455"></li>
  ....
</html>
```

how do I get the value for all the ids alone in python using BeautifulSoup ?
the desired output is : `["123","3455"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the list you want, use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It can be done in one line as follows (last line):

```
html = '<html> <li id="123"></li><li id="3455"></li> </html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

attrs = [li['id'] for li in soup.find_all('li')]
```

Comment: You're welcome @Abhinav - I saw your edit, but `find_all` is the current syntax for BeautifulSoup, and findAll for BS 3 - but it works in BS 4 as well.

Comment: Ok ! i am using bs3 i guess... so it didn't work for me, good to know that.

Answer (score 0):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

foo = '<html> <li id="123"> </li> <li id="3455"></li> </html>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(foo)

for id in soup.html.findAll('li'):
    print id['id']
```